# Programmatically pass constant 'NOT LIKE' parameter

Tags: search, parameters, yii, constants

Is it possible to pass parameter to the search method programmatically in Yii?
I have tables Team and Workers and I create `add workers to the team` functionality. I want to show CGridView searching which will show all workers except those assigned to the actually editing team. How to achieve it?

Comment: You need to show us some code!

Comment: post some relevant codes

Answer (score 0):

Usually the gridview is calling the `search()` method of your model, you could easily edit this method to add an optional parameter like:

```
public function  search($notLike = false){
    if($notLike) {
        //add the new sql condition not like
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I can even declare CDbCriteria as an argument and pass it, but how to use it in CGridView? It works until you change one of the filders in the gridview - after that it completely ignores the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition($column, $keyword, $escape, 'AND', $like)
```

For example

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('CustomerName', 'Jo', false, 'AND', 'NOT LIKE')
// Column 'CustomerName'
// Value to look for 'Jo'
// escape value? false
// append to query using 'AND'
// Compare using Not Like
//     This should generate: "... AND CustomerName LIKE 'Jo'"
```

Check out [`CDbCriteria->addSearchCondition()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail)